# HEVC to mp4 video converter

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

While converting files HEVC to mp4 using python the error is comming by ffmpeg. I have used moviepy to convert video to mp4 formate.

Used moviepy Package to convert but throwing error

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def convert_to_mp4(input_file, output_file):
    try:
        clip = VideoFileClip(input_file)
        codec = 'libx264'  # Default codec is libx264
        if clip.reader.codec_name == 'hevc':
            codec = 'libx265'
        clip.write_videofile(output_file, codec=codec, audio_codec='aac')
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error converting video: {str(e)}")
        return False

def upload_and_convert(input_file_path, output_folder):
    if os.path.exists(input_file_path):
        # Convert to MP4
        mp4_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, 'converted2.mp4')
        success = convert_to_mp4(input_file_path, mp4_file_path)

        if success:
            print(f"Conversion successful. MP4 saved at {mp4_file_path}")
            return mp4_file_path  # Return the path of the converted MP4 file
        else:
            print("Failed to convert the video.")
            return None
    else:
        print("Input file not found.")
        return None

input_file_path = '/Downloads/sample-hevc-file.hevc'
output_folder = '/Downloads'
download_link = upload_and_convert(input_file_path, output_folder)

if download_link:
    print(f"Download the converted MP4 file here: {download_link}")
```

**Error**

```
rror converting video: MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file C:/Users/kjrah/Downloads/sample-hevc-file.hevc.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, hevc, from 'C:/Users/kjrah/Downloads/sample-hevc-file.hevc':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1200k tbn, 15 tbc
At least one output file must be specified

Failed to convert the video.
```

Throwing this error except HEVC mostly files are working fine.